# I am not able to understand what the text is trying to say about the connection of capacitors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

I have added the image of the part of page (the specific statement is highlighted), why does the text says that the capacitors are not connected in series ? And why the text says that they are not in parallel connection ?

[image]

Comment: When there is a battery at C1, one does not say that the battery is either in parallel or not  with C2? . With the battery there and closing S the capacitor will charge. Having a charged capacitor in C1 replaces the battery and the logic should be the same?

Comment: That's what I thought of

Comment: Poor wording in the text.

Answer (score 11):

So, why do we worry if capacitors are in series or parallel?
It is often the case that deciding whether a number of capacitors are in series or parallel will enable an equivalent capacitance to be found.

What the text is saying is that using an equivalent capacitance formula, be it for series capacitors or parallel capacitors, for the circuit shown in the diagram does not work and to suggest that it is a parallel or series circuit is of no benefit.

You will remember that when deriving the capacitors in parallel equivalent capacitance a key point is that the potential difference across each capacitor is the same, but for the circuit that you have asked about that is not necessarily true.
When deriving the series equivalent capacitance a key point is that the charge on each capacitor is the same and again that is not generally the case for this circuit.

Comment: "but for the circuit that you have asked about that is not necessarily true", Sir it'll be true in equilibrium, because charges will flow until both the Capacitors attain equal potential difference between their plates.

Comment: @erik So you then have two capacitors with the same potential across them.  What extra will you gain by saying that they are in parallel?

Comment: I got it sir, thank you again

Answer (score 5):

The concepts of *in series* and *in parallel* are only useful if there is a battery in the circuit that is maintaining a constant potential difference across different parts of the circuit. So if there were a battery at S instead of a switch then we could say that the capacitors were in series with the battery, and we could use the "in series" formula to calculate an equivalent capacitance for the two capacitors together.

However, with a switch at S, the concepts of *in series* and *in parallel* are not useful (I suppose you could say that the capacitors are in series with the switch, but that is likely to cause confusion). Instead there is a fixed quantity of charge in the circuit which needs to be split between the two capacitors so that the capacitors have equal (and opposite) potential differences across their plates.

Comment: "Instead there is a fixed quantity of charge in the circuit which needs to be split between the two capacitors so that the capacitors have equal (and opposite) potential differences across their plates" this line made all of that clear. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As the problem is stated it has no solution in the realm of Kirchhoff's equations applied to a circuit consisting of *ideal capacitors*  and *ideal switches*. Missing is the acknowledgment that Kirchhoff's equations (the source of the concepts of parallel and series connections) must always be accompanied with initial conditions AND continuity (connection compatibility) rules. The continuity rules demand that all charges, fluxes, inductor currents and capacitor voltages be always continuous and be at least piece-wise differentiable functions of time.

In the case of *ideal* capacitors the initial conditions are the initial charges, or voltages, which are given here. But when the *ideal* zero-resistance switch connects the two capacitors the voltage on $C_2$ jumps discontinuously from $0V$ to whatever the voltage of $C_1$ is, and THAT discontinuity is not allowed; it also creates an infinite current impulse.

One simple way of handling the problem is to include a *small* series resistance in the switch. The current will be finite and the voltage on both capacitors will be continuous. Including the series resistor results in a series connection model for the two capacitors but without an external source the nomenclature series/parallel is not very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need 'circuit context' if you are going to use the terms *series* and *parallel* meaningfully.

If the switch were replaced by something other than a switch or a piece of wire, even if only by a voltmeter or a resistor, we'd say that the capacitors are in series.

If we close the switch so that the top plates are connected together, as are the bottom plates, then connect some other circuit component(s) between the top plate and the bottom plate of either capacitor, we'd say that the capacitors are connected in parallel.

What I'm implying is that use of the terms *series* and *parallel* is more about topology than about voltages and charges. For example, referring to my second paragraph, the capacitors would still be in series if one were charged and the other had no charge, or indeed if neither were charged.

With the switch closed in the diagram in your textbook and no other component connected, I'd say that the terms *series* or *parallel* are inapplicable.

Answer (score 0):

@Erik
Perhaps re-drawing the circuit will help.
As shown below, when the switch is open, there are two capacitors. When the switch is closed, you can think of the circuit as one large capacitor that contains an unevenly distributed internal charge.
![re-drawn circuit] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S6Yed2YGAAVilgb5djpyfaf87Bvs6MCO/view?usp=drive_link)

I hope this is of help.